# Why is an asterisk being replaced with all directories under / after deployment?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, erb

I was hoping someone could give some insight to a problem I noticed on my last deployment.  I have an erb page with some javascript in it.  There were no problems until I tried to multiply numbers.  For some reason, after I deploy to the server, all asterisks are replaced with what looks like the output of the command

```
~$ ls /
```

So, to clarify, why does this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  a = b * 2;
</script>
```

become

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  a = b bin boot dev etc lib sbin usr var 2;
</script>
```

when rendered after I deploy?  This is just frustrating now.  Thanks in advance for any ideas or answers.

EDIT
I checked my source code and the asterisks aren't changed.  They only change when I try to hit the page. The problem was not with capistrano.

Comment: How are you deploying this file? By copying it over from your source repository? By using `echo`?

Comment: copying my source repo with capistrano. [Capistrano on github](https://github.com/jadb/capcake/wiki/Introduction-to-Capistrano)

Comment: It's rather worrying that something like this would end up getting executed in the shell, or interpolated in some fashion. Usually the `git` method just copies files over verbatim.

Comment: Sorry tadman, I was wrong about source code changing.

Answer (score 1):

It's due to shell expansion. If the current directory is `/`:

```
echo *
bin boot dev etc home lib lib64 logs_backup media mnt opt proc root run sbin srv sys tmp usr var
```

Try

```
"a = b * 2"
```

if you want to calculate, use

```
a=$(echo "$b*2" | bc)
```

(There is likely a better way than the above.)

Comment: Sorry I think you misunderstand.  My source code is changing when I deploy to a server.  I'm not typing any *'s into the terminal.

Comment: How is that possible?  I fixed this problem by moving the javascript function to a global js page.

Comment: WTF. Can't help you more, but that's a shell expansion - check how capistrano actually copies files.

Comment: Sorry Tass, my source code was not changing. Only some files are affected by this. But putting my code inside ""'s will not work.